# Is there any way I can output a file from my Cypress test runner?

Tags: typescript, cypress

There are error files generated by an API that my tests call. The errors are output to a file, & screen displays the error file id.
I can download these files using the apiKey & the fileID whilst the test is still running, but after that, it is gone.
It would be very handy if I could output this file to my browser (via a download) so I can see it. At the moment, I can only get it by adding cy.pause() to my test code to pause the test after the error file has been created.

Line of code that shows me fileID:

```
cy.log('resultsCsvFileId: ' + res.import.resultsCsvFileId);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can actually use `cy.writeFile()` as below,

```
cy.request('https://dummy.url').then((response) => {
  cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/response.csv', response.import.resultsCsvFileId)
})
```

You can refer the docs here - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile.html#JSON

But, this overwrite the file every time. Here, is the workaround to append the required data to a CSV file,

1. Install `npm` package `csvdata` https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvdata

   `npm install --save-dev csvdata`
2. In the cypress project -> plugins `index.js` file place the below code,

```js
const csvdata = require('csvdata')
on('task', {
    log(message) {
        csvdata.write('./logs.csv', message, {
            append: true,
            header: 'stats,numusers'
        })
        return null
    }
})
```

3. Then from now on, all the `log` task will get appended to the CSV file,

```js
describe('My First Test', function() {
    it('Visits the Kitchen Sink', function() {
      cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io')
      cy.contains('type').then(($el) => {
          var data = "inService, 30";
          cy.task('log', data)
      })
    })
})
```

**Reference:** https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1249

**Update 1:**
The issue specified above is now resolved and append option is now available,

```
cy.writeFile('path/to/message.txt', 'Hello World', {flag: "a+"}))
```